# Formula in excel that does average to all cells that matches the number in a row, the former number and next number

Tags: excel

I need to do a formula in excel that does average to column of votes if it matches to the season in that row, former, and next season (except from the first and last season). For example, if I am in a row on season 3, I need to do average of all the votes in seasons 2,3 and 4.
Right now I tried :
=AVERAGEIFS(I$2:I$237,B$2:B$237,$B2,B$2:B$237,IF($B2=1,$B2,$B2+1),B$2:B$237,IF($B2=10,$B2,$B2-1))

(I- is the column of votes, B - is the column of seasons)
But it returns error: #div/0!

This is a small example of the table.

I would like for help to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Averageifs, the different conditions have an AND relationship - so at the moment you are asking for rows that match both previous season AND next season which is impossible. There aren't any, so you get the #DIV/0 error.

Try it with a range instead:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(I$2:I$10,B$2:B$10,">="&B2-1,B$2:B$10,"<="&B2+1)
```

[image]